# Rename factor variable in multi ggboxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, ggpubr

The below code creates two side by side boxplots with titles "pun" and "mv". How can I change the titles to "punishment" and "morality"?

```
ggboxplot(d, x = "Condition.Name", 
y = c("pun", "mv"),
combine = TRUE,
color = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF", "#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF"),
xlab = 'Condition',
ylab = 'Total score'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to pass a version of your data with modified column names.

The following replicates your own set-up fairly well:

```r
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(1)

d <- data.frame(Condition.Name = rep(c("Breakfast", "No Breakfast"), 100),
                pun = rnorm(200, 100, 10),
                mv = rnorm(200, 98, 10))
```

So using your own plotting code we get a similar plot to yours:

```r
ggboxplot(d, x = "Condition.Name", 
y = c("pun", "mv"),
combine = TRUE,
color = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF", "#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF"),
xlab = 'Condition',
ylab = 'Total score'
)
```

[image]

To change it, we simply rename the columns in the copy of `d` that we pass to `ggboxplot`. The simplest way to do this is probably with `dplyr::rename`:

```r
ggboxplot(dplyr::rename(d, Punishment = pun, Morality = mv), 
          x = "Condition.Name", 
          y = c("Punishment", "Morality"),
          combine = TRUE,
          color = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF", "#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF"),
          xlab = 'Condition',
          ylab = 'Total score'
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that works well. Do you also know how to change the names of the breakfast/no breakfast?

Comment: @samf94 sure - just add `+ scale_x_discrete(labels = c("New label1", "New label2"))` after the closing bracket of your call. If you have found this answer helpful, please read [what should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) . Thanks